# Unable to Post on Pinterest using their API

Tags: c#, json, pinterest

I'm receiving a 400 Bad Request error message when posting a pin on Pinterest.  It works using Postman, but doesn't work programmatically. Using C#, has anyone been able to successfully post a pin on Pinterest without using the pinsharp wrapper?

```
private void postPinterest(string messages, string id, string usertoken, string image, string boardname, string username)
{
    string link = null;
    boardname = boardname.Replace(" ", "-");

    string board = username + "/" + boardname;
    string url = "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins?access_token=" + usertoken;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(board))
        sb.Append("&board=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(board));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(messages))
        sb.Append("&note=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(messages));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link))
        sb.Append("&image_url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(link));

    string postdata = sb.ToString().Substring(1);
    PostData(url, postdata);
}

private object PostData(string url, string postdata)
{
    object json=null;
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //  req.Accept = "application/json";
        using (var stream = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] bindata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postdata);
            stream.Write(bindata, 0, bindata.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        string response = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
        return json;
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        if (wex.Response != null)
        {
            using (var errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wex.Response)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(errorResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string error = reader.ReadToEnd();                          
                    return json;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return json;

}
```

**EDIT:**

It doesn't work using the JSON format or x-www-form-urlencoded format.

I changed the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and now I'm receiving the error message below.  I receive 400 Bad Request error using JSON format:

```
"{\n  \"message\": \"405: Method Not Allowed\",\n  \"type\": \"http\"\n}"
```

Comment: Why you set ContentType as application/json? You post not json but application/x-www-form-urlencoded or something.

Comment: I thought I tried that before...I switched the contenttype to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and now i'm receiving the below error message

"{\n  \"message\": \"405: Method Not Allowed\",\n  \"type\": \"http\"\n}"

Comment: I have no idea about pinterest api, so might only guess. First maybe you need to make your queries over https, not http. Second, maybe you need to include access_token in post data (not include in query string).

Comment: Unfortunately, the url string is using https and the token is supposed to be in the url string not the post data.  The website that contains the code loads using https also.  Thanks for your comment

Comment: It's weird, because if i'm getting a 405 that means the method type "POST" is incorrect.  Piniterest requires the POST method for adding pins.  It's either the method type or the uri.

Comment: Why you are doing Substing at line Sting postdata = sb.ToString().Substring(1), this is removing the first '&' from query string.

Comment: I had the issue of "Method Not Allowed" just now. Turns out it was because I was doing a post on "v1/pins" as you are. Doing it on "v1/pins/" fixed it (note the trailing '/').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the the parameter that you are posting.
In the Api i could find `board` as a parameter but both `note` and `image` comes under `field` parameter which specifies the return type JSON.
As per documentation on [this page](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/) you can post in this format

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/anapinskywalker/wanderlust/pins/?
    access_token=abcde&
    limit=2&
    fields=id,link,counts,note
```

So I tried the following and its getting response

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/?access_token="YourTokenWithoutQuotes"&fields=id%2Ccreator
```

Would suggest you to first test the Api you are hitting putting a breakpoint inside the `PostData` function and check if the passed url is in the correct format and compare it with [Pininterest API Explorer](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/api-explorer/).
As you might have already received `authorization code` and `access token` so I am assuming your post function should be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string postPinterest(string access_token,string boardname,string note,string image_url)
      {

            public string pinSharesEndPoint = "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/?access_token={0}";

            var requestUrl = String.Format(pinSharesEndPoint, accessToken);
            var message = new
            {
                 board = boardname,
                 note = note,
                 image_url = image_url
            };

            var requestJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(message);

            var client = new WebClient();
            var requestHeaders = new NameValueCollection
{

    {"Content-Type", "application/json" },
            {"x-li-format", "json" }

};
            client.Headers.Add(requestHeaders);
            var responseJson = client.UploadString(requestUrl, "POST", requestJson);
            var response = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseJson);
            return response;
}
```

Comment: Hi Vishal, would you mind adding some clarification to your code as to what it does. This will help the person who's asking the question to understand what's happening and what was wrong with their attempt to solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: The accepted answer is a GET this uses a POST which seems to be the current requirement